# Remove Blank Spaces from Mobile Number using PHP preg_replace

Tags: php

We have mobile numbers stored in db in format 0789 121 928

We need to remove the blank spaces from the number so it is 0789121928

This is what I have used before to remove ',' in $ fields, and am trying to modify.

```
<?php
$value1A = $row_person_select['mobile'];
$value1A = preg_replace("|,|","",$value1A); // Strips out commas in incoming value ie 2,340.00 > 2340.00
$totalA = $value1A;
echo $totalA; 
?>
```

I have tried the obvious of replacing the ',' with ' ' but does not work?

Ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression here.

```
$mobile = str_replace(" ", "", $row_person_select['mobile']);
```

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) is sufficient if you just want to remove spaces.

---

But just to answer the actual question, you can use `"|\s|"` with preg_replace to remove *any* whitespace characters.

Comment: The same can be used for the commas version too

Comment: I just changed "|,|" to "|\s|" and it worked.. Thank you.. Should I remove any of the other code?

Comment: It might be that your spaces are actually tabs or something, in which case the regex is the better alternative. -- About your code; you could use fewer temporary variable names and `..1A` variable suffixes. It's not clear why you make so many assignments.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Will look at cleaning up

Answer (score 1):

For removing space inside numbers try this

`preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $num)`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$input = "text  07786 000 000 6493 5446 t e x t ";
$output = preg_replace("/(\d)\s+(\d)/", "$1$2", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output; //text  0778600000064935446 t e x t
```